# SVG Как работает rotate() при анимации для CSS

Tags: css, html5, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Подскажите, пожалуйста как действует значение rotate() при трансформациях SVG графики ? Вот простой пример

```css
#preloader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.rec {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}


/* .b6{
  animation: 13s mov6 linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
} */

@keyframes mov6 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(135px, 64.64px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(140px, 64.64px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(150px, 64.64px);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="preloader" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
            <path class="rec b6" transform="rotate(-45 135 64.64)" fill="#f00" d="M115.4 44.6h40v40h-40z"/>
</svg>
```

Я пытаюсь привязать SVG путь к CSS но у меня ничего не выходит. По идеии если же rotate(a,b,c) a-угол поворота, b- X координата  c - Y координата пути относительно верхнего левого угла SVG. Задаю CSS анимацию, но не отрабатывает. 
Хочу получить зацикленное движение квадрата как на рисунке.

[image: SVG rotate]

Comment: я плохо понял что нужно получить в итоге, но в целом - вращение происходит вокруг начала координат, можно сначала расположить объект так, чтобы при вращении вокруг начала координат он вращался как нужно, повернуть вокруг центра, а потом все это положить в группу и подвинуть куда надо

Comment: Не совсем понял, но думаю, что это поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55425245/animate-scale-rotate-svg-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я пытаюсь привязать SVG путь к CSS но у меня ничего не выходит.

В CSS пока нет анимационной привязки объекта к пути.

Но в svg есть команда анимации - [`animateMotion`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/animateMotion), которая позволит это сделать.

Пояснения смотрите в Комментариях кода.

```css
#recRed {
transform-box: fill-box;    
transform-origin:50% 50%;
} 

#pathRec {
fill:none;
stroke:#1CF11B;
stroke-width:1px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="preloader" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="50 30 200 200" >
<!-- Трасса анимации прямоугольника -->
<path id="pathRec"   d="m 135,64 -43,44.5 43.44,33.8 39.9,-46.7z">
     
</path>   
   <g id="gr1">      
  <!-- Красный прямоугольник -->
 <path id="recRed" transform="translate(-135,-65) rotate(45)"  fill="#f00" d="M115.4 44.6h40v40h-40z">
   
  <animateMotion  dur="3s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite">
        <!-- Привязка красного прямоугольника к трассе анимации-->
    <mpath xlink:href="#pathRec"></mpath>
     
   </animateMotion> 
 </path> 
 </g>

</svg>
```

*Приложение адаптивно, если нужны фиксированные размеры, то замените проценты в шапке svg на значения в пикселях.*

**Update**

Нарисованную зелёную трассу можно не показывать `stroke="none"`

Comment: Я правильно понял, что нельзя через CSS заставить двигаться части SVG, будь то  path rect и тд. ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 привязать к пути SVG и двигаться вдоль него фигуры SVG, image может только svg/ А CSS может вполне просто перемешать фигуры svg с помощью команд, но привязать к пути и двигаться вдоль него CSS не может